# Getting the wrong number of rows when i apply filter and run the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro and it was working fine but i got some issue which im unable to resolve it.i could not post the code because its nearly 800 lines and The macro is about importing new codes which are unique, so I have run the macro without filtering any columns for the first time, it was working fine but then applied the auto filter for columns and filtered some rows and starting running the macro it was still working fine but when i run the macro , the next time the numer of rows counted is showing different

case 1

```
I have 35000 rows in my workbook that are old and run the macro working fine
imported 100 unique rows
```

case 2

```
i have closed and reopened the file and
now applied filters to the sheet and the last row that i can see is 24000 
but rows count is still 35000 in vba thats what i wanted , then run macro
it gave 100 and working fine
```

case 3

```
now i have reopened my workbook and run the macro as normal then applied filters
for the sheet that has both newly imported and old entries now it gives 24000 
as rows count that is where the last filtered row is
```

but it should be 35000 as total count could anyone tell me why?

Comment: you may have to reapply filters. When you apply autofilter, Excel assumes a range over which creating the filter. If you add data when the filter is applied, the new range may not be considered as part of the filter. I don't know if I made myself clear but you can have a try by your self and see (without VBA).

Comment: If your macro consists of just one Sub or Function then I would be concerned at it being 800 lines long. It might be worth breaking it down into a number of smallers Subs/Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to my own question when i tried it more and more by experimenting on new workbook, and what I observed is

```
rows= activesheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Gives 35000 when filters are not applied

but

```
rows= activesheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Gives 24000 because that is where the last row that can be seen using filter and that is what it returns.

I have tried it by taking a small new workbook with some random values in 10 cells and took the count, it gave me 10 as answer , then i applied filter for a value where its last occurence is 6 , then surprsingly , it returned the value as 6 then i understood what it was doing

```
     A
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     1
     6
     2
     3
     4
```

without filters i got 10 as count now i applied filters for value 1 then i got the count as 6, that is where the last occurence of 1 is.Be careful while using filters :)

I hope it helps some other people who sees these post Thanks!